# Call php function in view from mustache and pass a mustache array value into the function call

Tags: kohana-3.3, mustache.php

I would like to pass an array value to a view function so that it can send back some HTML based on that value sent. I want my system to either send back textarea, textbox or radio button.

On my mustache I have `{{#get_question}}{{type}}{{/get_question}}` where type can have any value from ["input","radio","comment"] The main headache I have is how to call this function and pass the parameter.

I would like to have a php function get_question which extracts the value passed in {{type}}, if type is not text, I would like to pass the value of type to my partial call `{{>}}` and dynamically load the partial represented by the {{type}}
I got this code sample from Kohana forums:

```
Hello, {{#caps }}{{ text }}{{/ caps }}!

    $m = new Mustache_Engine(array(
        'helpers' => array(
            'caps' => function() {return function($text, $m) {
                  return strtoupper($m->render($text));
            }}
        )
    ));
```

I can't seem to get it to work from my view since I have to enclose it in another `function(){}` block.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a headache because you're fighting against the fundamentals of Mustache :)

This is a bit backwards from the "Mustache way". Instead of trying to shoehorn in logic via lambdas, you should extract the logic into your view/viewmodel/model, and limit your template to simple sections and string interpolations. Something like this would do the trick:

```
{{# questions }}
  {{# is_input }}{{> input }}{{/ is_input }}
  {{# is_radio }}{{> radio }}{{/ is_radio }}
  {{# is_comment }}{{> comment }}{{/ is_comment }}
{{/ questions }}
```

Then each question view/viewmodel/model would answer to `is_input()`, `is_radio()` and `is_comment()`.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing while setting the is_input or is_radio to true/false and passing the partials parameter to the view.